# Split string on spaces except file paths

Tags: java, regex, parsing, command-line-interface

My java application features a small command line. In order to parse the arguments first the line is read in and than chopped into an array using `string.split("\\s+")`. The arguments are of the form *name:value* and usually neither *name* or *value* are supposed to have spaces.

Introducing a new feature i ran into a problem when *value* is supposed to be a file path. If the path contains spaces (escaped or not) the chopping algorithm will of course just split up the path.

**Q:** What regular expression would allow me to split the string into an array of arguments without splitting (escaped) file paths.

---

I consider escaped paths to be of the form `/folder/part1\ part2.txt`, but alternative syntaxes when reasonable are valid too.

If easier `string.split(" ")` is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the syntax: `/folder/part1\ part2.txt`:

A regular expression to solve this would need a **negative look-behind**, to check whether the character before the pattern we're looking for wasn't a `\`. The regular expression would be `(?<!\\)\s+`: `(?<!\\)` is the look behind part, `\\` is the pattern we don't want to see. `\s+` is the pattern we're looking for - a space of some kind. To use this regex in java you'd have to escape it correctly yet, as in: `string.split("(?<!\\\\)\\s+")`.

This works for UNIX style file paths, you might have to remove the backslashes yet if you want to pass the file into a `new File()` for example.

---

For the syntax `"/folder/part1 part2.txt"`:

This might be a more universal approach, but introduces additional work. The idea is to loop over the string and every time we see a space we save the previous part into a list, unless the space is in the escaped part. For example:

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean escaped = false;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    if(!escaped && (c == ' ' || c == '\t')) {    // Space in non-escaped part
        parts.add(stringBuilder.toString());     // Put buffer in list
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    } else if (c == '"')       // Escape sign
        escaped = !escaped;    // Toggle escape status
    else
        stringBuilder.append(c);    // Add char to buffer
}
parts.add(stringBuilder.toString());    // Put the last buffer into the array
```

If necessary the list can be converted to an array using

```
String[] args = parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()])
```

This format allows for UNIX and Windows style paths. The resulting array will contain the file path **without** the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

The best code is not written code. So, do not parse command line yourself. Use one of popular libraries. For example the good old [jackarta cli project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) or modern, annotation-based library [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I hadn't heard of the args4j library before, it seems to be an interesting approach. Regardless whether I will step over to a library or not, it'd be interesting to know if there is a solution to the specific problem though.